# are xampp>mySqlDatabase service>phpmyadmin totally separate from mysql-server command Line?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have both xampp and mysql-server installed on Ubuntu.
I first installed xampp then mysql-server.
obviously both services don't run together I am aware of that.
if they both use mysql why doesn't phpmyadmin sync itself with mysql-server?
if that's not possible How do I specify in my php application to connect  to phpmyadmin web based or to mysql-server insatlled software?

problems I'm facing now:
.The password for root which I provided in mysql-server is NOT synced with phpmyadmin root password
.I don't see databases created using command line in mysql-server in phpmyadmin and vice versa
.whenever I try to connect to mysql in php It only checks with phpmyadmin users and databases.How can I check with mysql-server users and databases?
.should I go back uninstalling xampp and mysql-server and this time install mysql-server first?

I mean are phpmyadmin totally seperate from mysql-server?
and how can I sync them?
my php only checks with phpmyadmin users and databases

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'some-pass', 'some-database');
```

Comment: XAMPP comes with mariaDB and will be listening on port 3306. MySQL installed as well will listen on port 3306. By default phpMyAdmin will be connecting with a database server running on port 3306.

Comment: If you dont want to use mariaDB, move it to listen on 3307 and then you can basically forget it. Or just never start mariaDB (thats what is really being ruin by XAMPP, even if it looks like and is called mysql)

Comment: SO you have **2 seperate DBMS Servers**. Which ever you start first will grab 3306 and answer to phpMyAdmin resuests. If you set a password when MySQL is running **it will not be set in mariadb** and visa versa

Comment: @RiggsFolly :If I don't start xampp>mysqlDatabaseService and Run only xampp>ApacheWebServer. and run service mysql start from terminal I should be able to listen to 3306 port?just did that nor my php application connects throwing error:Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/shopV4/config/config.php:21,nor the localhost/phpmyadmin connects to Db Error:MySQL said: Documentation Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Comment: @RiggsFolly :mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directoryConnection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.phpMyAd tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection.